# when using only one authentication methon in firebase-auth-ui then it is not showing sign-in button

Tags: android

I am using firebase-auth-ui with only phone authentication method. But i am facing problem that firebase-auth-ui is not showing activity with sign-in button, it directly showing the activity to enter the phone number to sign-in. but i want it to show the activity with "sign-in with phone" button.

[image]

**Here is code:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_logo);

    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if (user != null){
        loggedIn = true;
        mobileNumber = user.getPhoneNumber();
        letMeIn();
    }else{
        goForLogin();
    }
}

private void letMeIn(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER, mobileNumber);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private void goForLogin(){
    startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance()
            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
            .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
            .setProviders(Arrays.asList(
                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.PHONE_VERIFICATION_PROVIDER).build()))
            .build(), LOGIN_REQUEST);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using one type of authentication, you need to build the UI your self and call the `goForLogin()`

Comment: is this a bug or i missed something.

Comment: it's not a bug you are using one type on authentication so it wont ask you you to choose between other types, if you add `email&password` or any other type it will shows the choosing login type UI